# python - Machine Learning 2D Regression with confidence bands

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, pytorch

I have measures of a variable versus time.
I want to obtain a regression with confidence bands so that the plot sounds like this:
[image]

Given an arbitrary `x`, I "predicted" the `y` and its confidence by evaluating mean and std of `N` closest measured points. But I feel like this is quite naive.

I was wondering if it is possible to obtain a similar result with Machine Learning, Neural Network, ...

I'm quite familiar with python, sklearn and pytorch so if you please could suggest a solution that implements those tools I would be very thankfull.

Comment: I have several animated examples of confidence intervals for different curve fitting problems at http://zunzun.com/CommonProblems/ with Python source code at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/commonproblems/src/master/ and these are 95% coonfidence intervals on the fitted model.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I checked them out: those sounds like y=ax+b fits, instead my measures don't have an analytical expression, and particularly are not on a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something like that with Gaussian Processes. For regression problems, you can use [`GaussianProcessRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor) from `sklearn`.

[This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpr-noisy-targets-py) is an example of how to use it to obtain the plot you are looking for.

Comment: this is what I also found looking around and your answer encourages me that this is a possible solution: nonetheless I had some difficulties in choosing the correct parameters to get a good fit (none that i tried was acceptable). Given the data I reported in the plot, if you have some experience with this algorithm could you hint some kernel, alpha, optimizer, ... that you think should work? Thank you!

Comment: I am not an expert at all, but I think it would help to subtract the empirical mean from your time series. As a kernel, the RBF is usually a good enough choice for time series. If you have the suspect your underlying data might be periodic you could use one based on trigonometric functions. If you still have difficulties, you should probably post the question on datascience stack exchange